# cannot understand for statement result

Tags: java

Our teacher in my AP Computer Science course gave us this code

```
final int LIMIT = 5;
int i, count;
for (count=1; count<=LIMIT; count++) 
{
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(count);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

When this code executes, the output is as follows

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

I do not have a good understanding of the `for` statement and I cannot understand why the code would print 1 once, 2 twice, 3 three times, ect. Can someone please try to explain this to me?

Comment: The second for loop executes `count` number of times (and prints count) and the first for loop increments the value of `count` by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a great question and covers the basics of `for` loops.*

### Thinking About For Loops: The Basics

Think about the code you have written above in this way:

A `for` loop does ("executes") what is enclosed in its body once for each time you specify - or, to think about it another way, until a condition that you specify is `false`. As the coder, you need to tell the program: [1] at what point to begin; [2] how many times to do it (better thought about as "*until when* to do it"); [3] and by how many the code should "count" (what we call "increment").

To demonstrate with pseudo-code:

`for ([1]; [2]; [3])`

**or**

```
for (where to begin; how many times; how to count) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Remember, as you "count", you are increasing - in the case of the first `for` loop - the `count` variable by the `how to count` piece (`count` + `how to count`). What you have in your above code is a **nested** `for` loop - a loop inside another loop (described, below). Referencing the pseudo-code I have written, above, your first `for` loop does the following:

```
for (start counting at 1; iterate once until count is greater than 5; increment count by 1)
```

### Your Question

Now, comes the piece that is throwing you. You have two variables to pay attention to because you have two for loops: `count`, in the first `for` loop (*used by the second*); `i` in the second. Each time your first `for` loop iterates, the first `for` loop must execute the second `for` loop (look at your code). Again, pay attention to the two variables - but, more importantly, the relationship between the variables in both `for` loops' conditions. The second `for` loop depends upon the first. Think about it this way:

As `count` is incremented (here, increased by one), the second `for` loop must execute its own operation that many times:

`for (i starting at 0; i not equal to count; increment by 1)`

So, at the first iteration you would see something like this:

`for (count = 1; count will always iterate once until condition false; increment){ }`
`for (i = 0; i < count (1); increment i){ }`

Result will be:

`1`

Then the first loop is incremented (`count` becomes `2`) and you get:

`for (i = 0; i < (2); increment i)`

Because the second loop will iterate until `i` is no longer less than `2` (**not including 2**), your result will be:

`22`

This relationship will continue until you get your final result:

`55555`

#### A Final Comment

Your teacher is looking to teach you a few different things with the code you provided, above, namely two: nested `for` loops; and how initializing your iterator (`i` and `count`) and the condition statement `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, etc.) affects the behavior of a loop.

Comment: "go until count is not equal to 5" That is wrong. It goes until count is greater than five. 1 != 5... The same applies to your statement "i not equal to count"

Comment: @MirroredFate I tried to change it to your suggestion. You and I were editing at the same time. Sorry! I am editing my response like a firestorm, right now (trying to flesh it out). Refresh your browser and the change should be there (?). Your distinction is an important one. Voted you up on your comment so you'd get credit for the change.

Comment: This was excellent and helped me and my friend who were struggling with For statements. You put it into java terms, while MirroredFate put it into english, i applaud you both

Comment: @theruss0n make sure you accept an answer. And, if you have the ability (can't remember when you are able to in SO), vote answers you like "up".

Comment: Have to wait until I have +15 rep before voting responses up or down

Answer (score 0):

The first for loop indicates that it will loop the contents `LIMIT` times(which is 5), incrementing `count` by 1 at the end of each loop. The second inner for loop indicates that number of times to print the number `count`.

Might be easier to understand with indentation of your code:

```
final int LIMIT = 5;
int i, count;
for (count=1; count<=LIMIT; count++) {
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        System.out.print(count);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You make an important point: properly indenting your code is a great way to visually distinguish between what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The first for loop starts at 1 and ends at limit 5.  The inner loop starts at 0 and goes to the current count.  So for the first iteration the inner loop will go from 0 to 1. This will print count 1 time which count is 1.  The second time through the outer loop the counter will be 2 so the inner loop will loop from 0 to 2.  It will print 2 twice.  The 3rd time through count will be 3.  The inner loop will loop from 0 to 3 and print 3 3 times.  Etc...  This is nested looping.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop will write 5 lines as LIMIT = 5

The second loop will write n times the current index of the first loop, for each line.

n equals the current index of the first loop. So line #1, one time 1, line #2, two times 2, ....

Answer (score 0):

You have two `for` loops, the outer loop starts `count` with a value of 1 and will iterate until `count` has a value greater than 5. The inner `for` loop will start with a value of 0 and will iterate until `i` has a value greater than or equal to `count`. So,

```
count <- 1
i <- 0
while (i < count) { print(count); i++; } // <-- 0 to 1 is a range of 1
newline();
```

Then

```
count <- 2
i <- 0
while (i < count) { print(count); i++; }  // <-- 0 to 2 is a range of 2
newline();
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to explain this by walking through the steps on by one...

```
final int LIMIT = 5;
int i, count;
for (count=1; count<=LIMIT; count++) 
{
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(count);
    }
   System.out.println(); //from the results you are getting, this statement should be here
}
```

To put this in human readable terms:

```
A. we have a number LIMIT that is 5
B. we have a number i and count
C. set the number count to 1
D. if the number count is less than LIMIT, do the following:
      1. set the number i to 0
      2. if the number i is less than the number count, do the following:
             a. print out the number count
             b. add 1 to the number i
             c. go back to step 2
      3. print out an empty line
      4. add 1 to the number count   
      5. go back to step D
```

So, if we go through the loops, here's what our variables become:

```
count is set to 1
count is less than 5
i is set to 0
i is less than count? yes, i is 0 and count is 1
print out the value of count (which is 1)
add 1 to i
i is 1
is i less than count? no, i is 1 and count is 1
print out a new line
add 1 to count
count is 2
count is less than 5
i is set to 0
i is less than count? yes, i is 0 and count is 2
print out the value of count (which is 2)
add 1 to i
is i less than count? yes, i is 1 and count is 2
print out the value of count (which is 2)
add 1 to i
is i less than count? no, i is 2 and count is 2
print out a new line
add 1 to count
count is 3
etc.
```

This continues until count is greater than 5, at which point it exists. As you can see from the pattern, the variable `count` determines which number gets printed, and the variable `i` determines how many times it is printed.

Comment: Nicely done. That's what I was trying to do. I like your steps.